# i just installed visual studio 2010 sp1 but i dont see asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

i just installed visual studio 2010 sp1 and i thought asp.net mvc3 came along with that

[image]

but when i go to create a new project i only see asp.net-mvc2 .  am i missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC 3 is not shipped with visual studio 2010 SP1
You have to add in to your VS2010 seperately through this link
http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3

Answer (score 3):

The Web Platform Installer is capable of chaining VS10 SP1, MVC 3, IIS Express and a bunch of other useful tools. More information available here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/03/15/visual-studio-2010-sp1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's a separate download afaik.  Here is a direct link to the download page: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d2928bc1-f48c-4e95-a064-2a455a22c8f6&displaylang=en

For more details, have a look at this page:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3